Why blinding doesn't work in Blazor form?
I am a beginner at Blazor. It's my first project using VS22 Blazor project Server side and I have this code in my page Home.razor :
@page "/"
@using WebReporting.Kernel
@using WebReporting.Components.Base

@inject UserAccess CurrentUser

<PageTitle>Page d'accueil</PageTitle>

<div>
  <!--  Model.Message-->
</div>

@if (!CurrentUser.IsInRole(TUser.AccessRights.User.ToString()) && !CurrentUser.IsInRole(TUser.AccessRights.Admin.ToString()))
{
  <EditForm Model="UserCred" FormName="Login" OnValidSubmit="@Login">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="userName" class="col-form-label col-md-2">Nom d'utilisateur</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <InputText id="userName" @bind-Value="UserCred.UserName" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password" class=" col-form-label col-md-2">Mot de passe</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <InputText id="password" @bind-Value="UserCred.Password" type="password" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Connexion</button>
  </EditForm>
}
else if (CurrentUser.User != null && CurrentUser.User.Identity != null)
{
...
}

Then in Home.razor.cs :
namespace WebReporting.Components.Pages;

using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

public partial class Home
{
  [Inject]
  private ILogger<Home>? _logger { get; set; }
  [Inject]
  private NavigationManager? _navigationManager { get; set; }
  [Inject]
  private IHttpContextAccessor? _httpContextAccessor { get; set; }


  public UserId UserCred { get; set; } = new UserId();

  public string? Message { get; set; }

  public async Task Login()
  {
    try
    {
      _logger!.LogInformation($"Login : {UserCred.UserName}, {UserCred.Password}");
      // Vérifier si un nom d'utilisateur et un mot de passe ont été fournis
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserCred.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserCred.Password))
      {
        // Recherche d'un utilisateur correspondant dans la base de données
        using DBInterface dbManager = new();
        TUser? dbUser = dbManager.GetAllUsers().FirstOrDefault(u => string.Compare(UserCred.UserName, u.Name, true) == 0);

        // Vérification du mot de passe
        if (dbUser != null && Simple3Des.DecryptString(dbUser.PasswordHash) == UserCred.Password)
        {
          _logger!.LogInformation("Login de l'utilisateur {user}", dbUser.Name);

          List<Claim> claims =
          [
            new(ClaimTypes.Name, UserCred.UserName),
            new(ClaimTypes.Role, dbUser.AccessLevelEnu.ToString())
          ];
          ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

          AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new()
          {
            AllowRefresh = true,

            IsPersistent = true,
          };
          _httpContextAccessor!.HttpContext!.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties).Wait();

          _navigationManager!.NavigateTo("/");
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      _logger!.LogError("Erreur dans {methodName} : {exceptionType} : {exceptionMessage}", $"{nameof(Home)}.{nameof(Login)}", ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message);
      throw;
    }

    Message = $"Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe invalide !";

    _navigationManager!.NavigateTo("/");
  }
}

public class UserId
{
  public string UserName { get; set; } = "";
  public string Password { get; set; } = "";
}

The Login function is called but UserCred.User and UserCred.Password are empty (not null).
I don't understand why the binding (field userName and password) doesn't work.
If I check in my browser debugger, I get a POST message with the correct data for UserName and Password.
Can someone help me, pls?

You need [SupplyParameterFromForm] attribute, then the EditForm binding will work.
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public UserId UserCred { get; set; } = new UserId();

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#input-components-and-forms

Yes!!! thank you very much I was banging my head over this problem for a while now. The tutorial are pretty variable on the exact requirement needed....
